# I have return jenkins pipeline and its contains three servers so based on server selection deployment should continue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
        //Cloning helm repo  into local
        stage('helm_update'){
            steps{
                dir('helm'){
                    git poll: false,
                        credentialsId:'Bitbucket-credentials',
                        url: 'git@bitbucket.org:exium-c2/gitops.git'
                    
                   // Changing values on jenkins local server based jenkins tag 
                    sh   (" sed -i   's/${APP_NAME}_tag=.*/${APP_NAME}_tag=${image_tag}/' xedge-vm/config/env-exe15")
                    sh   ("sed  -i   's/${APP_NAME}_tag=.*/${APP_NAME}_tag=${image_tag}/' xedge-vm/config/env-exe16")
                    sh   ("sed  -i   's/${APP_NAME}_tag=.*/${APP_NAME}_tag=${image_tag}/' xedge-vm/config/env-exe17")
                    sh   ("sed  -i   's/${APP_NAME}_tag=.*/${APP_NAME}_tag=${image_tag}/' xedge-vm/config/env-exe18")
                    sh   ("sed  -i   's/${APP_NAME}_tag=.*/${APP_NAME}_tag=${image_tag}/' xedge-vm/config/env-exe19")
                    sh   ("sed  -i   's/${APP_NAME}_tag=.*/${APP_NAME}_tag=${image_tag}/' xedge-vm/config/env-exe20")
                    sh   ("sed  -i   's/${APP_NAME}_tag=.*/${APP_NAME}_tag=${image_tag}/' xedge-vm/config/env-exe21")
                    
                    //echo "exe15" 
                    sshagent(['xedge-vm']) {
                        sh '''
                             scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xedge-vm/config/env-exe15  centos@52.14.164.158:/exedge-volume/exedge/env-exe15
                             ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no centos@52.14.164.158       "cd /exedge-volume/exedge/ && hostname"
                           '''
  //echo "exe16"
                    sshagent(['xedge-vm']){
                        sh 
                        '''
                        scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xedge-vm/config/env-exe16    centos@54.145.46.212:/exedge-volume/exedge/env-exe16
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no   centos@54.145.46.212       "cd /exedge-volume/exedge && hostname"
                        '''
                    }
                   
                        }   
            
                    }
                   
                }
        
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

'' It should work If i selected all the servers at time to deploy & and it should work if i selected one server. Could someone help in this. As I tried but i could able to achieve selecting one server at a time.''

Comment: 16:24:50  WorkflowScript: 51: Expected a step @ line 51, column 21.
16:24:50                         if (env.exe_server == "exe15"){
16:24:50                         ^
16:24:50  
16:24:50  WorkflowScript: 61: Expected a step @ line 61, column 21.
16:24:50                         if (env.exe_server == "exe16"){
16:24:50                         ^
16:24:50  
16:24:50  2 errors

Comment: getting above error